Hierarchical Structured URLs Web Scraping BeautifulSoup and recursive functions
Muy buenas,
Estoy tratando de obtener una Clasificación Jerárquica para la taxonomía de los hongos utilizando este sitio web https://speciesfungorum.org/Names/fundic.asp?RecordID=Fungi&Type=K a través de BeautifulSoup y funciones recursivas. Sin embargo, me he quedado atascado en el primer nivel y no soy capaz de llegar al nivel base (Especies). Este es mi script hasta ahora:
# Base URL for the Species Fungorum site
base_url = "https://speciesfungorum.org/Names/"

# Initialize lists to store the taxonomy data
domain_list = []
kingdom_list = []
phylum_list = []
class_list = []
order_list = []
family_list = []
genus_list = []
species_list = []

# Function to scrape each page
def scrape_taxonomy(url, domain, kingdom, phylum='', class_name='', order='', family='', genus=''):
    print(f"Processing URL: {url}")  # Debugging: print the current URL being processed
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Extract all links on the page
        links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
        for link in links:
            href = link['href']
            text = link.text.strip()

            # Check if the href contains 'RecordID'
            if 'RecordID=' in href:
                next_url = base_url + href
                
                # Handle taxonomy levels based on URL and text
                if 'Type=P' in href:
                    print(f"Found Phylum: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum=text)
                elif 'Type=C' in href:
                    print(f"Found Class: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name=text)
                elif 'Type=O' in href:
                    print(f"Found Order: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name, order=text)
                elif 'Type=F' in href:
                    print(f"Found Family: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name, order, family=text)
                elif 'Type=G' in href:
                    print(f"Found Genus: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name, order, family, genus=text)
                elif 'genusrecord.asp?RecordID=' in href:
                    # Species level
                    print(f"Found Species: {text}")  # Debugging
                    species_list.append(text)
                    domain_list.append(domain)
                    kingdom_list.append(kingdom)
                    phylum_list.append(phylum)
                    class_list.append(class_name)
                    order_list.append(order)
                    family_list.append(family)
                    genus_list.append(genus)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {url}: {e}")

# Start the scraping process from the Kingdom level
start_url = base_url + "fundic.asp?RecordID=Fungi&Type=K"
scrape_taxonomy(start_url, domain='Eukaryota', kingdom='Fungi')

# Create a DataFrame with the collected data
taxonomy_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Domain': domain_list,
    'Kingdom': kingdom_list,
    'Phylum': phylum_list,
    'Class': class_list,
    'Order': order_list,
    'Family': family_list,
    'Genus': genus_list,
    'Species': species_list
})

¿Alguna idea de qué está pasando? Soy nuevo con el uso de las funciones recursivas pero creo que son la mejor solución para esta estructura jerárquica.
Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y un saludo,

Imprimiendo el contenido de la respuesta es obvio el problema, para las subsecuentes peticiones la tabla que retorna el servidor está vacía, mostrando un bonito texto "No records found"...
El problema es que la página usa cookies y cuando se intentan acceder a enlaces de "niveles inferiores" sin estas cookies de sesión el servidor retorna la tabla vacía. A veces es simplemente un mecanismo para dificultar lo que estás haciendo, el scraping.
En principio se soluciona con solo pasar las cookies de la sesión a las subsiguientes llamadas a requests.get. Se puede hacer con el argumento cookies de requests.get, obteniendolas de la primera llamada con el atributo response.cookies, pero es más simple si usas requests.Session:
def scrape_taxonomy(
        requests_session, url, domain, kingdom,
        phylum='', class_name='', order='', family='', genus=''
    ):

        # ...
        response = requests_session.get(url)
        # ...
            scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, ...,  order=text)
        # ...


session = requests.Session() 
scrape_taxonomy(session, start_url, domain='Eukaryota', kingdom='Fungi')

Aparte de eso, creo que te falta el condicional para la subclase (y la lista si quieres almacenarla):
elif 'Type=S' in href:
    print(f"Found Subclass: {text}")  # Debugging
    # ...

El código completo debería ser algo así:
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Base URL for the Species Fungorum site
base_url = "https://speciesfungorum.org/Names/"

# Initialize lists to store the taxonomy data
domain_list = []
kingdom_list = []
phylum_list = []
class_list = []
subclass_list = []
order_list = []
family_list = []
genus_list = []
species_list = []


# Function to scrape each page
def scrape_taxonomy(
        requests_session, url, domain, kingdom,
        phylum='', class_name='', subclass_name='', order='', family='', genus=''
    ):
    print(f"Processing URL: {url}")  # Debugging: print the current URL being processed
    try:
        response = requests_session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Extract all links on the page
        links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

        for link in links:
            href = link['href']
            text = link.text.strip()

            # Check if the href contains 'RecordID'
            if 'RecordID=' in href:
                next_url = base_url + href
                # Handle taxonomy levels based on URL and text
                if 'Type=P' in href:
                    print(f"Found Phylum: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum=text)
                elif 'Type=C' in href:
                    print(f"Found Class: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name=text)
                elif 'Type=S' in href:
                    print(f"Found Subclass: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name=text, subclass_name=text)
                elif 'Type=O' in href:
                    print(f"Found Order: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name, subclass_name, order=text)
                elif 'Type=F' in href:
                    print(f"Found Family: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name, subclass_name, order, family=text)
                elif 'Type=G' in href:
                    print(f"Found Genus: {text}")  # Debugging
                    scrape_taxonomy(requests_session, next_url, domain, kingdom, phylum, class_name, subclass_name, order, family, genus=text)
                elif 'genusrecord.asp?RecordID=' in href:
                    # Species level
                    print(f"Found Species: {text}")  # Debugging
                    species_list.append(text)
                    domain_list.append(domain)
                    kingdom_list.append(kingdom)
                    phylum_list.append(phylum)
                    class_list.append(class_name)
                    subclass_list.append(subclass_name)
                    order_list.append(order)
                    family_list.append(family)
                    genus_list.append(genus)
                    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {url}: {e}")

# Start the scraping process from the Kingdom level
start_url = base_url + "fundic.asp?RecordID=Fungi&Type=K"
session = requests.Session() 
scrape_taxonomy(session, start_url, domain='Eukaryota', kingdom='Fungi')

# Create a DataFrame with the collected data
taxonomy_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Domain': domain_list,
    'Kingdom': kingdom_list,
    'Phylum': phylum_list,
    'Class': class_list,
    'Subclass': subclass_list,
    'Order': order_list,
    'Family': family_list,
    'Genus': genus_list,
    'Species': species_list
})

Por cierto, no suele ser mala idea agregar un pequeño tiempo de espera entre peticiones, algunos servidores te bloquerán si detectan una tasa demasiado elevada.

Un millón de gracias! Ahora funciona perfectamente. Tomo nota del tiempo de espera entre peticiones. Eres un fenómeno!
